# Get Value from Array object

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have Array Like a table object. I need to get single value from that array.

Array has name, ID, address

I need to get value of name from that array by using JQuery.

var jqData = new Array();
jqData = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");

that column name pass like a parameter from another method

Comment: please post your code,html ,or create fiddle

Comment: like this array[index].name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume, your data is similar to this,
then you can get the value like

```
 var data = [{ "id": 1, "name": "test1", "address": "addr" }, { "id": 2, "name": "test2", "address": "addr"}]
    alert(data[0].id);
    alert(data[1].name);
    alert(data[0].address);
```

**Edit**

```
var columnName = "name";
alert(data[1][columnName]);
```

Courtesy: Satpal

Comment: that column name pass like a parameter. how can i get that

Comment: @user2710638, I think you want this `var columnName = "name";alert(data[1][columnName])` You should read [__Bracket notation__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

Answer (score 0):

AS per your requirement

```
var data = [{{ "id": 3 },{"name":"pratik"},{"address":"india"}}    , {{ "id": 52},    {"name":"sam"},       {"address":"usa"}}   ]

    alert(data[0].name);
    alert(data[0].id);
```

Get what you want to get using data[Index].
which variable name you want

Now as per your REQUIREMENT
you can get  ID,Name,Address dynamically

```
function (uniqueNames) { 
/// uniqueNames is column name given by another method 
/// uniqueNames == Id <== just assume 

jqData = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data"); 
    for (j = 1; j < jqData.length; j++) 
    { 
    txtValue = jqData[j].[0]; //Get id 
    txtValue = jqData[j].[1]; //Get name
    txtValue = jqData[j].[2]; //Get address

    } 
}
```

Comment: think that "name" column pass like a column name how can i use this

Comment: means what ?sorry didnt get you.

Comment: column name passing like a parameter from one method to this. So we cant use like data[0].columnName. How can get that

Comment: Yes you can do like => data[0].columnName  ,data[0].address

Comment: function (uniqueNames) {
// uniqueNames is columnName



}
How can get now machan

Comment: please provide more Code,dont get you .

Comment: function (uniqueNames) {
     /// uniqueNames is column name given by another method
 /// uniqueNames == Id <== just assume

           jqData = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
           for (j = 1; j < jqData.length; j++)
           {
               txtValue = jqData[j].  <<<==== this is the problem
           }

}

Comment: So you want is just to get jqData[j].name , jqData[j].id ,In dynamic way,correct?

Comment: yeh ... Now i Got that one its getlike
jqData[j][columnName]

Comment: Thanks ,i appreciate that ,now is it answer to your Question,if yes ,dont forget to make as Correct ans